# asp.net chat using RegisterWaitForSingleObject?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, multithreading, .net-4.0

I've *managed* to do  server response in chunks to  a client ( im *learning* implementing my own chat)...

I have 2 versions (one work , the other isnt).

here is the code for the working version.

```
  static EventWaitHandle _waitHandle = new AutoResetEvent(false);
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       var t = HttpContext.Current; //capture the context
       Response.Write("starting...");
       Response.Flush();
       new Thread(() => Waiter(t)).Start(); //start a new thread for later setting the wait handle...
       _waitHandle.WaitOne();  //wait - STOP THE THREAD !!
    }

private object Waiter(HttpContext httpContext)
{
    httpContext.Response.Write("111");
    httpContext.Response.Flush();
    Thread.Sleep(4000); 
    httpContext.Response.Write("222");
    httpContext.Response.Flush();
   /*... 2 more responsed like 222*/
    _waitHandle.Set(); //wakt the other thread
    return null;
}
```

this is the output :

[image]

please notice that the asp.net thread isnt release until the set() command.

lets talk about version 2 :

ive **[read](http://acessoparadesenvolvedor.blogspot.co.il/2011/07/c-thread-synchronization-essentials-18.html)** that :

> If your application has lots of threads that spend most of their time
>   blocked on a wait handle, you can reduce the resource burden by
>   calling ThreadPool.Register WaitForSingleObject.

so my code is :

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
1       var t = HttpContext.Current;
2       Response.Write("starting...");
3       Response.Flush();
4       RegisteredWaitHandle reg = ThreadPool.RegisterWaitForSingleObject (_starter, Go, t, -1, true);
5       new Thread(() => { Thread.Sleep(4000); _starter.Set(); }).Start();
       ...
    }
```

theres a problem ...

after line 4 - it continues ( doesnt block) and the response is finished ( the asp.net response)...

I **thought** it suppose to **wait** **until i signal it** ...?

how can i fix the second version ?( i want it to act like ver 1 - but without the *resource burden* issue ( from the link above)

Comment: What are you exactly are you trying to accomplish?  You should avoid using the ThreadPool in ASP.NET, unless you like playing with a Pandora's box.

Comment: @BryanCrosby hi. Im trying to accomplish the thread to wait until i signal it. ( like version 1 here). i know that i should avoid holding expensive threadpool thrad in asp.net.....isnt version 2 suppose to help here ? the problem as i said - is that it doesnt blocking the thread.... after line 4 its just continues....and closing the response..... am i clear ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`RegisterWaitForSingleObject` doesn't block your current thread; it basically spins up a thread pool thread (new or reused) and calls `WaitForSingleObject` in there before calling your "callback".

There's nothing you can do to "fix" that because that's the way it is suppose to work.